# Disable XML-RPC via snippet

Tags: xml, xml-rpc

I am testing disabling XML-RPC on WP 6.2.2 via the following snippet:

```
add_filter('xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false');
```

But that isn't working. I can still access xmlrpc.php fine. I tried to add it in functions.php, using the WPCode plugin and Code Snippets plugin as well. I can disable XML-RPC fine using the .htaccess code, but I wanted to know if this way still works since this is mentioned in almost every "How to" article about XML-RPC.

Comment: This filter will  not change if the file is accessible or not.

Answer (score 2):

From the [`xmlrpc_enabled` filter docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/xmlrpc_enabled/):

> Contrary to the way it’s named, this filter does not control whether XML-RPC is fully enabled, rather, it only controls whether XML-RPC methods requiring authentication – such as for publishing purposes – are enabled.

To *fully* disable XMLRPC, you might be able to use the [`xmlrpc_methods` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/xmlrpc_methods/) and return an empty array:

```
add_filter( 'xmlrpc_methods', 'wpse416991_disable_xmlrpc' ); 
/**
 * Disables XMLRPC methods.
 *
 * @param  array $methods The XMLRPC methods.
 * @return array          An empty array to disable all methods.
 */
function wpse416991_disable_xmlrpc( $methods ) {
    return array();
}
```

Per @birgire's comment, you could further simplify this using [`__return_empty_array()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__return_empty_array/):

```
add_filter( 'xmlrpc_methods', '__return_empty_array' );
```

If that doesn't work, you can block access to the XMLRPC file in your `.htaccess` file (though that's outside of the WordPress scope):

```
<Files "xmlrpc.php">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

Comment: ps: __return_empty_array() might also become handy to use here

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.